# Modelling full sequence with LSTM in Flux-Julia

Tags: machine-learning, julia, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, flux.jl

I am trying to train an LSTM to model a full sequence y based on a sequence of x (not just the last item or a classifier). With the following code, the training does not work although the loss function works. It seems that the dot formalism does not work with train! ? Any ideas how I could do it? In Keras it's so simple....
Thanks in advance,
Markus

```
using Flux

# Create synthetic data first
### Function to generate x consisting of three variables and a sequence length of 200
    function generateX()
        x1 = Array{Float32, 1}(randn(200))
        x2 = Array{Float32, 1}(randn(200))
        x3 = Array{Float32, 1}(sin.((0:199) / 12*2*pi))
        xdata=[x1 x2 x3]'
        return(xdata)
    end

### Generate 50 of these sequences of x
    xdata = [generateX() for i in 1:50]

### Function to generate sequence of y from x sequence
    function yfromx(x)
        y=Array{Float32, 1}(0.2*cumsum(x[1,:].*x[2,:].*exp.(x[1,:])) .+x[3,:])
        return(y')
    end
    ydata =  map(yfromx, xdata);
    
### Now rearrange such that there is a sequence of 200 X inputs, i.e. an array of x vectors (and 50 of those sequences)
    xdata=Flux.batch(xdata) 
    xdata2 = [xdata[:,s,c] for s in 1:200, c in 1:50]
    xdata= [xdata2[:,c] for c in 1:50]
 
### Same for y
    ydata=Flux.batch(ydata)
    ydata2 = [ydata[:,s,c] for s in 1:200, c in 1:50]
    ydata= [ydata2[:,c] for c in 1:50]
    
### Define model and loss function. "model." returns sequence of y from sequence of x
    import Base.Iterators: flatten
    model=Chain(LSTM(3, 26), Dense(26,1))
    
    loss(x,y) = Flux.mse(collect(flatten(model.(x))),collect(flatten(y)))
    
    model.(xdata[1]) # works fine
    loss(xdata[2],ydata[2]) # also works fine

    Flux.train!(loss, params(model), zip(xdata, ydata), ADAM(0.005)) ## Does not work, see error below. How to work around?
```

#### Error message

```
Mutating arrays is not supported

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] (::getfield(Zygote, Symbol("##992#993")))(::Nothing) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/lib/array.jl:44
 [3] (::getfield(Zygote, Symbol("##2633#back#994")){getfield(Zygote, Symbol("##992#993"))})(::Nothing) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/ZygoteRules/6nssF/src/adjoint.jl:49
 [4] copyto! at ./abstractarray.jl:725 [inlined]
 [5] (::typeof(∂(copyto!)))(::Array{Float32,1}) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [6] _collect at ./array.jl:550 [inlined]
 [7] (::typeof(∂(_collect)))(::Array{Float32,1}) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [8] collect at ./array.jl:544 [inlined]
 [9] (::typeof(∂(collect)))(::Array{Float32,1}) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [10] loss at ./In[20]:4 [inlined]
 [11] (::typeof(∂(loss)))(::Float32) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [12] #153 at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/lib/lib.jl:142 [inlined]
 [13] #283#back at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/ZygoteRules/6nssF/src/adjoint.jl:49 [inlined]
 [14] #15 at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Flux/oX9Pi/src/optimise/train.jl:69 [inlined]
 [15] (::typeof(∂(λ)))(::Float32) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [16] (::getfield(Zygote, Symbol("##38#39")){Zygote.Params,Zygote.Context,typeof(∂(λ))})(::Float32) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface.jl:101
 [17] gradient(::Function, ::Zygote.Params) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Zygote/fw4Oc/src/compiler/interface.jl:47
 [18] macro expansion at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Flux/oX9Pi/src/optimise/train.jl:68 [inlined]
 [19] macro expansion at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Juno/oLB1d/src/progress.jl:134 [inlined]
 [20] #train!#12(::getfield(Flux.Optimise, Symbol("##16#22")), ::typeof(Flux.Optimise.train!), ::Function, ::Zygote.Params, ::Base.Iterators.Zip{Tuple{Array{Array{Array{Float32,1},1},1},Array{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,Array{Float32,1}},1}}}, ::ADAM) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Flux/oX9Pi/src/optimise/train.jl:66
 [21] train!(::Function, ::Zygote.Params, ::Base.Iterators.Zip{Tuple{Array{Array{Array{Float32,1},1},1},Array{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,Array{Float32,1}},1}}}, ::ADAM) at /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/mreichstein/julia_atacama_depots/packages/Flux/oX9Pi/src/optimise/train.jl:64
 [22] top-level scope at In[24]:1

loss(xdata[2],ydata[2])
```

Comment: The problem might be that collect internally mutates an array, which is not supported by Zygote.jl, flux's ad backend. See if you can write the loss without the use of collect. E.g. `sum(x->abs2(-(x...)),zip(model.(x),y)) `

Comment: Thanks for your hint! When calling the loss I then get `MethodError: no method matching -(::Array{Float32,1}, ::Float32)`. The problem is that `model.(x)` returns an array of arrays of length 1, and somehow I need to unpack it to do math operations. Any other way to do it? Sorry I am novice to Julia.

Comment: Tried to unpack by hand with `yhat=[]; for e in model.(x); append!(yhat, e[1]);
    end` but then get again the Mutate error

Answer (score 0):

Well, following Frederik's path, the following loss seems to work, but frankly I don't quite like it, so I still wonder if there are more elegant/idiomatic/efficient(?) solutions...

```
function loss(x,y) 
    yhat=model.(x)
    s=0
    for i in 1:length(yhat)
        s+=(yhat[i][1] - y[i][1])^2
    end

    s/=length(yhat)
    s    

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at [Buffer](https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/utils/) for the mutating array.